# How to add timestamp(month_year) to the file after matching specific string?

Tags: ubuntu, sed

I want to add time stamp inside the file only after matching specific string:

timestamp format: 03_2016

file contains "**$channel_name Policy**" string, I want to replace this string with "**$channel_name Policy_03_2016**"

content of file which I want to add timestamp:

```
package_path=/LSB/Packages/Policy
channel_path=/LSB/Channels/$parent_channel_name/$channel_name Policy
erratum_path=/LSB/Errata/$erratum_type Policies/$erratum_name
errata_path =/LSB/Errata/$parent_channel_name/$channel_name Advisory Roll-Up Policy
package_path=/LSB/Packages/Unapproved/$channel_name
```

Required file format:

```
package_path=/LSB/Packages/Policy
channel_path=/LSB/Channels/$parent_channel_name/$channel_name Policy_03_2016
erratum_path=/LSB/Errata/$erratum_type Policies/$erratum_name
errata_path =/LSB/Errata/$parent_channel_name/$channel_name Advisory Roll-Up Policy 
package_path=/LSB/Packages/Unapproved/$channel_name
```

Right now I'm using following command to add timestamp to file:

```
sed -i "s/$channel_name Policy/$channel_name Policy_$(date +%m_%Y)/g" filename
```

but this command is replacing all occurrences of **Policy** with **Policy_03_2016**
like this:

```
package_path=/LSB/Packages/Policy_03_2016
channel_path=/LSB/Channels/$parent_channel_name/$channel_name Policy_03_2016
erratum_path=/LSB/Errata/$erratum_type Policies/$erratum_name
errata_path =/LSB/Errata/$parent_channel_name/$channel_name Advisory Roll-Up Policy_03_2016
package_path=/LSB/Packages/Unapproved/$channel_name
```

Is there any solution for this question?

Comment: Escape the `$` in `$channel` (e.g. `s/\$channel...`) otherwise it will expand to nothing and your command will resolve to `s/ Policy/ Policy_03_2016/g`

Answer (score 2):

`$` is special to the shell within double quotes as it's used for parameter expansion (like in `$var`, `$1`, `$channel_name`), arithmetic expansion (like `$((1+1))`) and command substitution (like `$(cmd)` which you *are* actually using here).

`$` is also special in regular expressions (like on the left-hand side of the `s/regex/replacement/` `sed` command) as it's the operator that means "end of the subject", unless you use `-E`/`-r` to enable *extended* regular expressions, it's not special unless the `$` is at the end of the regexp itself or followed by `\)` (or `\|` where supported). Still, it's a good habit to escape it.

Both the shell inside double quotes, and `sed` in its regexps support `\` as an escaping operator to remove the special meaning of characters. `\` can also escape itself in both cases.

So, here, you could do:

```
sed -i "s/\\\$channel_name Policy/\$channel_name Policy_$(date +%m_%Y)/g" filename
```

That is, `\\\$` to *escape* `\` itself and `\$` for the shell so that `\$` is passed to `sed` where `\` escapes `$` again. On the right hand side `\$` is enough as `$` is not special in the replacement part of the `s/regexp/replacement/` command.

Though not POSIX, this would also work in any shell that I know:

```
sed -i "s/[$]channel_name Policy/&_$(date +%m_%Y)/g" filename
```

`[$]` is another way to *escape* `$` in a regexp. `[...]` matches on a *set* of characters, here comprising only one: `$`. While for the shell `[$]` is unspecified by POSIX, I don't know of any shell that doesn't leave it as is. You'd need `[\$]` for that shell code to be POSIX compliant  though.

We're also using `&` in the replacement which stands for *the string that was matched by the regexp*.

Another option would be to use *single quotes* for most of the string (inside which `$` is not special), and double quotes for the command substitution, still escaping the `$` in the regexp even though it's not strictly necessary:

```
sed -i 's/\$channel_name Policy/&_'"$(date +%m_%Y)/g" filename
```

Note that you need `$(...)` to be double quoted as otherwise split+glob would be applied on it.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by 'don_crissti', you have to escape the dollar sign otherwise it tries to get a variable content (which is empty in your case).

Alternatively it would be safer if you use a different separator than '/' as you also have slashes in your file. However it is not an issue in your case as long you do not use them in the replacement expression.

My working solution:

```
sed -i 's!\$channel_name Policy!&_'$(date +%m_%Y)'!g' policies.txt
```

The second possible improvement is the usage of the `&` in the replacement as it is exactly the searched expression plus some extra.

And third, in my test I was only able to make the command `$(date +%m_%Y)` working when outside of the `sed` expression (wrapped by single quotes).

I tried in `GNU sed` (the above line) and with `OSX sed` as well but none of them where able to interpret properly the `$(command)`.

Comment: Note that `$(date +%m_%Y)` ends up being unquoted here, so split+glob applies to it. That means it would fail in contexts where `$IFS` contains `_` or decimal digits for instance.